# hiddenFille data can Not getting In Android Api 30

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**here my code i try with my latest android 11 os device and i search in internet but i not find any solution also it working in android 10 device perfectly but not working in latest os device thanks**

```
    WhatsappStatusModel whatsappStatusModel;
    String targetPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses";
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    allfiles = targetDirector.listFiles();
```

Comment: On an Android 11+ device your app will not see files of other apps. Unless they are media files or ... `and i search in internet but i not find any solution ` Strange, as only on stackoverflow your problem has been reported several times last year.

Comment: @blackapps i try to fetch hidden image file from whatsapp media